# Prevent form submission if any input value is not found in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form where the user adds rows, and on each row there are inputs, where the user types in a value, and then a translate value appears beside it. The lookup occurs via a javascript array.

A boiled down example of how it works is here: https://jsfiddle.net/kc4fes2w/7/

In this example there is just one user entered value on each row, and beside that, the description associated with that user entered value, if there exists such a translation in the array. (in the example it consists of just XXX and YYY)

I want to prevent the submission of the form if any of the user inputted values isn't found in the array. In other words, if the `desc` div ever says "not found" then I don't want the user to be able to submit the form.

This is my attempt:

Javascript:

```
function checkform(fm) {
    var desc = $("#desc");
    if (desc.text().indexOf("not found") !== -1) {
    alert('You have invalid value(s). Please correct this.');    
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" onsubmit="return checkform(); event.preventDefault();" />
```

As you can see in the fiddle, this doesn't work.

Comment: You should change your `lookup_arr` to an object, i.e. `var lookup_arr = {}`, becase you use strings as keys. It sort of works, but now you have an empty array with strange additional properties like `XXX`.

Comment: it's possible to fix your code and make it work as you expected: https://jsfiddle.net/kc4fes2w/12/ but there were so many easily debuggable errors that you probably should have just fired up developer console and fix them one by one. Starting with `console.log(desc)` in the `checkform` function (which was just `""`) and going back from there.

Answer (score 1):

Return `false` when you do not want the form submission to go through:

```
function checkform() {
    var desc = $("#desc");
    if (desc.text().indexOf("not found") !== -1) {
        alert('You have invalid value(s). Please correct this.');    
        return false;
    }
}

<input type="submit" onclick="return checkform();" />
```

Comment: Missed that, thanks, I still can't get it to work though (https://jsfiddle.net/kc4fes2w/9/)

Comment: @BrianDeMilia - for the button - you need to set `onclick` event, for the `form` tag - `onsubmit`.

Comment: Again, thanks, it still won't return the error though: https://jsfiddle.net/kc4fes2w/10/

Comment: @BrianDeMilia - since html in your fiddle does not have a DOM element with `id="desc"` and `desc.text()` is an empty string, the execution does not enter the `if` block.

Comment: You create mltiple rows with `<div id="desc">` in each of them, while `id`s have to be uniqe. Then getting `$('#desc')` may be unpreictable, but you sort of worked around this problem by replacing these divs with error messages (you overwrite contents of `td` which contains `div#desc` with the message).

Comment: Is there a way to check if any div of any name anywhere on the page has the text "not found"? Or if any div whose name starts with "desc_", for instance, contains text "not found"? On my actual page the IDs are unique with an ascending row number for each div's ID. But there can be a variable number of them.

Comment: @BrianDeMilia - you setting "not found" content to a cell, but checking a `div` for it. As to your question - look at jQuery.each: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this !!

modify your submit button, keep it disabled in the beginning -

```
<input id="submit" type="submit" disabled onsubmit="return checkform(); event.preventDefault();"/>
```

then you can enable or disable depending on your logic, like this -

```
if (exists) {
    $this.closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html(lookup_arr[this.value])
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
} else {
    $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
    $this.closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).html('not found')
}
```